# How to properly make SOLR backups

Tags: solr

Is there a way, to make `SOLR` **backups** daily, without restaring `SOLR`?
I mean `SOLR`'s feature.

Comment: what did you mean by solr backups? want to take back of solr index?

Comment: documents, with indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backup of of your index (which contains the documents) can be started  via http-request

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/yourcore/replication?command=backup
```

See [Making and Restoring Backups of SolrCores](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Making+and+Restoring+Backups+of+SolrCores)
and

[Solr 5.2: quick look on Solr backup functionality](http://solr.pl/en/2015/06/22/solr-5-2-quick-look-on-solr-backup-functionality/)
for more information.

So if you want a daily backup make a cronjob to call this url regularly.