# SolrCloud index replication

Tags: solr, replication, sharding, solrcloud

I have prepared Solr index. Now I'm trying to replicate this index to all nodes in SolrCloud cluster. In master slave I did it without problems, when I defined ReplicationHandler with Master and Slaves with master-url. But how I can do it with SolrCloud?

Comment: SolrCloud is different from master-slave model. Solr cloud have concepts of shards and replica of shards for handling the replication. I would suggest you read some more documentation from Apache Solr. I have well configured and documented example.

Comment: In particular, replicationFactor and numShards when creating the collection sets these parameters automagically for you.

Comment: I've read a lot of documentation and up and run ZooKeeper and SolrCloud in Docker. I understand, how replication works in SolrCloud and that is a different from Master-Slave. My question was - how to make auto replication indexes? Do you know - how I can do the same for SolrCloud?

Comment: Be aware - that my question was not about replication process inside (I clear understand that and saw source code also), but if I have prepared Solr index - I need to replicate it in collection. In master-slave I can specified master URL and send "fetchIndex" request, but what I need to do in SolrCloud?

Comment: My best suggestion is to set up SolrCloud, create the collection with the numShards and replicationFactor settings you want, then load the index from the disk with the replication/backup command: [how to make Solr backups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466588/how-to-properly-make-solr-backups). If it works, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SolrCloud does not have a concept of master & slave. If there are two (or three) replicas, Zookeeper will decide who the leader is amongst the replicas.

The leader in this case will act as the master. The other ones will work as a slave (they will replicate the replica of the leader).

If the leader replica is dead, Zookeeper will assign a new leader amongst the replicas.